# In AngularJS with "Controller as" syntax and no $scope injection, where is the $scope?

Tags: angularjs

The `Controller as` syntax confuses my a little bit. I understand both ways of delivering data from the controller to the view, once through `Controller as` syntax and the other through injecting $scope and declaring everything on top of it.

But when I am write code:

```
     <div ng-controller="AddVMController as vm">
        <input ng-model="vm.number1" type="number" />
        <input ng-model="vm.number2" type="number" />
        <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="vm.add()">Add</button>
        <h3>{{vm.result}}</h3>
     </div>
```

What are the relations between `$scope` and `vm`? One is contained in the other?

Comment: I found good explanation here http://codetunnel.io/angularjs-controller-as-or-scope/.

Comment: Your `$scope` is `vm`. `vm` is merely the alias or name you give it in your view, this is useful if you have many different controllers. When using `controller as` you do not inject `$scope` into your controller, you use its context.

Comment: @ste2425 I think you are wrong because when you access `vm.number1` it works, but `$scope.number1` doesn't, and not even `$scope.vm.number1` or `vm.$scope.number1`. So they are not the same.

Comment: @MickelSierra `$scope` IS `vm`. It is merely aliased. When `$scope` is injected into your controller you never access the `$scope` directly in the view. So `$scope.vm.number1` would never work, nor would `$scope.number1`. The `$scope` variable is nonexistent in your user code when using `controller as`. `vm` is the EQUIVALENT of your `$scope` object except is is available in your view not controller. It is available in your view so you can distinguish between multiple scope objects if you use multiple controller in the same view. Otherwise you have to guess which `$scope` an object came from.

Answer (score 0):

So you have a controller object bound to your HTML view. There is also `$scope` instance which is a descendant of the $rootScope. `$scope` and controller are different things but they both are always there.

Here is a little confusing thing, even though if you use controllerAs - there is anyway `$scope` involved behind the scene. In fact, `vm` is only available in the view because there is a reference `$scope.vm = controllerInstance`. But with controllerAs syntax you deal with sort of prefix for all your view variables which helps a lot if you have nested scopes.